# Can I customize the XP bar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a custom map, and I want the XP bar to display the numbers I want it to, instead of the amount of experience the player has, like for countdowns and stuff like that. So: can I customize the numbers displayed there or is it not possible?

I'm using Minecraft 1.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not** possible to have the xp bar display anything other than experience points. **However**, if the players in your map don't collect xp (or you store custom xp in the scoreboard) you can set the xp bar to any number you like, by first removing any levels:

```
/xp -9999L @p
```

And then adding the amount you'd like:

```
/xp 1234L @p
```